# Admob stopped displayed, i repaired app and resubmission of displaying making me crazy

Tags: android, google-play, admob

My app has been stopped on Google Play and after that i received e-mail about stopping ads serving into this app. So i repaired app, submitted new version into Google Play, app has been approved and is available again, but without ads.

So i filled this form:
https://support.google.com/admob/v2/contact/appeal_policy_violation
And described what changes I  made to my app comply with their program policies.

After the 4 resubmission i always get same reply:

```
GOOGLE PLAY REMOVAL: AdMob publishers are not permitted to abuse or promote the abuse of any Google product, such as Google Play, YouTube, or Blogger. This includes circumventing, or providing the means to circumvent, the policies or terms of these or other Google products, such as by allowing users to download YouTube videos.

If your app is removed by Google Play policy enforcement, please contact Google Play about an app removal here. If Google Play reinstates your app, please submit an appeal to our team.
```

I don't know what can be wrong on my app and because nobody from Admob team is not able to give me clear answer i don't know what to do.

Many thanks for any advice or help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question to ask the Admob support

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question.
Anyway, once your app gets suspended you must appeal for reinstatement. There's no way to resubmit it like you claim because the app's page is greyed out.

It seems you just published a new version with different package name. You should create new ad units for your approved app in the play store.

As for the suspended app, you'd have to appeal for reinstatement, if google reinstates it, you can contact admob to re-enable ad serving.